# Co/Contra-Variance with input and output

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an issue with co/contra-variance.  I understand you can't have both input and output.  So here is a simple example:

```
public interface A<T>
{
    T Object {get;set;}
}

public interface B
{
    // Some stuff
}

public class BImplementor : B
{ }

public class Implementor : A<BImplementor> {}
```

Suppose you have these classes and I'm wanting to write a method like this

```
public void Command(B obj)
{
    var a = (A<B>)Unity.Resolve(typeof(A<>).MakeGenericType(obj.GetType());
    a.Object = obj;
}
```

I'm using Unity to resolve a `A` of the specifc implementor of `B` (specifically `Implementor`), but all I know about it is that it is an `A<B>`.  I don't know of a way to do this directly and I don't think it is actually possible, but does anyone know of a workaround to simulate what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you cannot have both input and output, so let's change `A<T>` to `A<in T>` so `Command` can assign `obj` to the `Object` property:

```
public interface A<in T>
{
    void SetObject(T obj);
}

public interface B { }

public class BImplementor : B { }

public class Implementor : A<BImplementor>
{
    public void SetObject(BImplementor t) { ... }
}
```

The `Command` method essentially does this:

```
public void Command(B obj)
{
    A<B> a = (A<B>)new Implementor();
    a.SetObject(obj);
}
```

But this cast can never succeed, because `A<B>.SetObject` must accept any `B` as input, while `Implementor.SetObject` accepts only `BImplementor` objects as input!

---

Since you now that you'll only ever pass a `BImplementor` to `A<B>.SetObject`, you can work around the problem using reflection.

Workaround 1:

```
public void Command1(B obj)
{
    object a = Unity.Resolve(typeof(A<>).MakeGenericType(obj.GetType());
    a.GetType().GetMethod("SetObject").Invoke(a, new object[] { obj });
}
```

Workaround 2:

```
public void Command(B obj)
{
    this.GetType()
        .GetMethod("Command2")
        .MakeGenericMethod(obj.GetType())
        .Invoke(this, new object[] { obj });
}

public void Command2<T>(T obj) where T : B
{
    A<T> a = Unity.Resolve<A<T>>();
    a.SetObject(obj);
}
```

Comment: I know that's the case.  The unfortunate thing is that I the method as written is actually type-safe because I know that Unity will return an object of type `A<BImplementor>`, but without doing a switch on every possible type I don't know of a way to cast it to the correct type.  I was hoping someone would have an idea for a workaround.  My ultimate goal is to be able to use Unity to resolve a `A` Of whatever specific type is passed into Command.

Comment: @Stephan: What about some dirty reflection? `object a = Unity.Resolve(...); a.GetType().GetMethod("SetObject").Invoke(a, new object[] { obj });`

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer I was going to get.  While that would work, it would be a last resort option for if nobody has any other possibilities for restructuring.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Stephan: I've added a different workaround to my answer that is less dirty IMO, but still using reflection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'm going to use the second workaround unless someone can give me a better suggestion.